# LaTeX Workshop does'nt work well (Recipe terminated with error.)

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

### Problem

I fail to build the LaTeX document on the VScode with LaTeX Workshop.
More preciously, ctrl + S can save the document but can't build the pdf. VScode warns "Recipe terminated with error".
The thing is that I was able to build the LaTeX documents earlier, but yesterday it abruptly didn't work well. Although I didn't change any option about LaTeX, I changed some settings about Python. For example, I uninstalled Anaconda and tried to create virtual environment of python with pipenv. However, I don't think those change are related to this problem...

### settings.json

settings.json is as following.

```json
{
   "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
   // ---------- LaTeX Workshop ----------
   "latex-workshop.intellisense.package.enabled": true,
   "latex-workshop.message.log.show": true,
   "latex-workshop.message.badbox.show": true,
   "latex-workshop.latex.autoClean.run": "onBuilt",
   "latex-workshop.view.pdf.viewer": "tab",
   "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [{
     "name": "ptex2pdf",
     "tools": [
       "ptex2pdf"
     ]
   }],
   "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [{
       "name": "ptex2pdf",
       "command": "ptex2pdf",
       "args": [
           "-l",
           "-ot",
           "-kanji=utf8 -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode",
           "%DOC%"
       ]
   }],
"latex-workshop.message.latexlog.exclude":["(Font shape `(JY1|JT1|JY2|JT2)(/.*)(sl|it|sc)'.*|Some font shapes were not available.*)"]
}
```

### Additional information

Since I hadn't used Workspace of VScode yet, but yesterday I started to use that. Since I thought it
may be the reason of the problem, now I stop using the worspace, but the situation doesn't change.

Furthermore, if I run on the cmd on VScode,

```
platex hoge.tex  
dvipdfmx hoge.dvi
```

the pdf was outputted successfully.

### environment

Windows10 Home 
VScode 1.49.0 
LaTeX Workshop 8.13.2